# Archiving only aspx pages in Jenkins Artifacts

Tags: jenkins, archive, artifacts

I have a Jenkins installation, wherein post successful build i archive the artifacts, so that in the Post build action, i can deploy the artifacts to my production website. However i do not find any option to only archive the aspx pages, like mostly we get when we publish the website.

However i see a File Pattern field in the Archive Artifacts plugin, however i am not sure, what pattern i can use so that Jenkins would provide me a published copy of the build (artifacts).

Could anyone please provide me file patterns i can use to get the Published copy, or is there any other way i can get the published copy to release on production in Jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pipeline job you can use this:

```
stage('archive') {
    logFiles = findFiles(glob: '**/*.aspx')
    if (logFiles.length > 0){
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/*.aspx', fingerprint: true
    } else {
        print ('no artifacts to archive')
    }
}
```

If you are not using a pipeline job, you probably can use the Ant pattern **/*.aspx on the job configuration

Comment: That was helpful, if you don't mind, i also want to deploy the artifacts from the successful build to production.i have the jenkins and production website on the same server, the Job is located in c drive and production website is in e drive.